# Preload Debian installer onto HDD

Tags: boot, installation, debian, installer

I have an old Pentium4 PC that I have rebuilt from spare parts and I am trying to install Debian on it so that I can use it as an homemade server.
Problem is, the motherboard (model P4S800-MX) won't boot from my USB 2.0 16GB drive formatted with FAT32 and prepared with unetbootin (from BIOS i set the boot device to USB ZIP first and then to USB FDD with no result, even after updating the BIOS to the latest version through floppy disk).

After losing a day, I thought if it would be possible to preload the Debian installer onto the hard disk from an another computer that has Windows on it or through an old Ubuntu LiveCD, but the guides I found only contemplate a drive that has already a bootloader on it or through partitioning.

All I want is to have the installer run and setup and download everything else from the internet like how the netinst image already does, is there a simple way to achieve that?
Burning the ISO to a CD-R is not an option, as I don't have an empty CD-R.

Comment: `I found only contemplate a drive that has already a bootloader on it` - So why is that a problem?  Just install a bootloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent an another whole day on this and finally I managed to install it

The steps I took are the following

1. I connected the drive to the PC and booted into an Ubuntu LiveCD session
2. Formatted the drive to FAT32 with gparted
3. Opened terminal and launched `sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt && sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sdb`
4. Downloaded [initrd.gz](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/i386/initrd.gz) and [linux](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/i386/linux) and put them under /mnt/Debian/
5. `sudo gedit /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and pasted this

   ```
   set timeout=5
   set default=0
   menuentry "Install Debian - netinst" {
       set root=(hd0,1)
       linux /Debian/linux root=/dev/sda1 ro
       initrd /Debian/initrd.gz
   }
   ```
6. Saved, powered off the PC, disconnected the drive and connected it to its destination host, powered on the host, followed the instructions and voilà I got Debian installed

I am not used to the linux environment and there might easier/faster/tool ways to do it, so more answers are welcome.

Comment: This is a pretty good way to do it, I had considered suggesting this method, since it was more likely to work, but raw writing of a disk image should have worked.

Comment: I just followed your comment about installing a bootloader, the most difficult part was finding out how to configure it (the Debian documentation doesn't contemplate GRUB2 and the grub-update command didn't help much in my case); on my first try, I used grubinst and ended up with having to repair Windows' bootloader haha.

Comment: I've tried this method and I could boot and start the installer but I could not explain to the gd installer that the installation media is right there in front of it's nose even if I mounted it myself.

Comment: My bad. The links in this response are no longer valid and I though any initrd.img and kernel will do but no, you have to find the netinst of the current version, in section 4.4 Preparing Files for Hard Disk Booting. Once you understand it, it's a simple process, you just copy 2 files and boot it with your existing GRUB if you have one. There's no longer a point for me to use sticks or anything as installation media.

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing else on the drive one simply thing you could do is to download the [boot.img.gz](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/hd-media/boot.img.gz) and then write it directly to the drive (not on the filesystem!).  The tool [rawrite](http://www.netbsd.org/~martin/rawrite32/) would permit you to do this.  This method will destroy anything that is already on that drive.

This will boot the mini installer directly into RAM, you then should be able to install the drive.  You will have to have a network device that is function with the default kernel, and if the install process fails you basically have to write the image to the drive again and start from scratch.

Links:

- http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/wheezy/main/installer-i386/current/images/hd-media/
- https://www.debian-administration.org/article/446/Boot_Debian_from_an_USB_device

Comment: This method worked for launching the installer, unfortunately it didn't go past the partitioning step as it gave a red error screen and corrupting the drive's partition table.

Comment: What exactly did the error say?

Comment: It said something like "Failed to create a file system. The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI1 (0,0,0) failed", I don't remember the exact error code though as I managed to install it in an another way